# assign "it" in each iteration (groovy)

Tags: string, groovy, immutability, trim

Hey, i try to trim each string item of an list in groovy

```
list.each() { it = it.trim(); }
```

But this only works within the closure, in the list the strings are still " foo", "bar " and " groovy ".

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
list = list.collect { it.trim() }
```

Comment: list = list.collect { it.trim() }

ty

Comment: Right, can't leave off parens with methods without parameters. Fixed.

Comment: A fantastic and tidy solution. Greatly appreciated. Meant I could do something like this: items = ViewDefinition.findAllByIdInList(params.id.split("-").collect { it as long })

Answer (score 6):

You could also use the spread operator:

```
def list = [" foo", "bar ", " groovy "]
list = list*.trim()
assert "foo" == list[0]
assert "bar" == list[1]
assert "groovy" == list[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Groovy Quick Start](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Quick+Start), using `collect` will collect the values returned from the closure.

Here's a little example using the Groovy Shell:

```
groovy:000> ["a    ", "  b"].collect { it.trim() }
===> [a, b]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really had to modify the list in place, you could use list.eachWithIndex { item, idx -> list[idx] = item.trim() }.

collect() is way better.

Answer (score 0):

@sepp2k i think that works in ruby

and this works in groovy
list = list.collect() { it.trim(); }